# upstart not running jar file once system has booted

Tags: 14.04, boot, java, startup, upstart

I have been working on several bits of code and done a fair bit of testing and looking around for answers before posting this, so I am hoping someone can help solve this with me.

The jar I am able to run with the upstart script manually, but it does not appear to start correctly on system boot. I have checked the upstart running services and it shows its started, but i dont think the actual jar file gets started correctly.

See below for the upstart script.

```
# /etc/init/test_app.conf
# Task to automatically start the test application service for demo
# dependant on mysql service

author "Simon Pascoe"
description "Run Java License Server"

expect fork

start on started tty1

pre-start script
        sleep 15        #wait some time to make sure interfaces have IPs
end script

#Respawn the process if it crashes
#If it respawns more than 10 times in 5 seconds stop
respawn
respawn limit 1000 1

expect fork

script
    cd /home/secure/License_Server_Application
    java -jar ServerSideLicensing.jar > /var/log/HW-test.log 2>&1
end script
```

Any help on this would be great

Comment: Upstart has a [`chdir`](http://upstart.ubuntu.com/cookbook/#chdir) option, so you don't need to do `cd`. Fix that, and you can remove the `expect` line as well. That should let us focus on the application itself.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try using muru's suggestions as well as changing the `start on` stanza to `runlevel [2345]` vs `started tty1`. You could also probably get rid of the sleep in the pre-start then.